# Name this card game

Tags: identify-this-game

Looking for the name of this card game:

**Layout:** I would lay four cards face down in front of each player, then four cards face up on the first four. Then I deal players 5 cards as their hand, then place the remainder of the deck in the center flipping over the top card and lay it beside the deck.

**Play:** each player has to play a card equal to or higher than the turned up card next to the deck from the 5 cards in their hand. Once you get through your 5 hand you then move on to the four cards face up. Then when you’ve gone through those you play the final four face down ones. First player out of cards wins.

**Rules:**

- If you can’t play an equal or higher card you have to draw up to 5 cards from the center deck, but if you draw a card you can play,  you can stop drawing and play that card immediately.
- 2’s and 10’s are wild, however with a 10 you can also play one extra card
- Aces are high

I’d really like to know it’s official name to see if there are variations of it! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out it’s a version of **Shed, Karma, Sh*thead, Palace**.  They fall in the category of games that entail discarding or shedding cards. I found it at the suggested similar questions.